# angular2- Observable getting data out of order

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

So I am using a getAll to get all of a school's Virtual Hosts, which comes back as a list of ID's (id's of the Virtual Hosts). Then, in order to get the data of the Virtual Hosts, I must call another get on each of the ID's. I do this through a for loop like so--

```
    this.apiService.findAll("virtualhosts/deltest")
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data.docs[0]
            error => console.log(error)

            for (let i = 0; i < this.data.VirtualHosts.length; i++) {
                this.apiService.findVH(this.data.VirtualHosts[i])
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                        this.data = data.docs[0]
                        this.jsonData = this.jsonData.concat(this.data)


                    })
            }


        });
```

The problem is, the apiService.findVH does not call the get in order of the ID's given by the apiService.findAll. Every time it gets called, it doesn't compute the ID's in order of the list (hence the indices of this.data.VirtualHosts[i] is different) How can I make the findVH (get call) call the indices in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) an observable:

```js
this
  .apiService 
  .findAll("virtualhosts/deltest")
  .flatMap(data => this.apiService.findVH(data.VirtualHosts))
  .subscribe(/* whatever you want */)
;
```

Comment: map or flatMap?

Comment: You can use both, but `flatMap` is definitely better.

Comment: then change your answer

Comment: how do i incorporate having to do a for loop through apiService.findVH into this?

Comment: you don't have to loop anything, `Observable` is an `Iterable Object`. Just look at my example.

Comment: map and flatMap are little different, cant interchange them :)

Comment: So how would I access each individual data in the Observable?

Comment: `flatMap` is a `flattened map`.

Comment: @joshua1991 did you try to log the `subscribe callback arguments` ?

Comment: How would I be able to do that? Sorry, Im completely new to observables

Comment: `.subscribe(thing => console.log(thing))`

Comment: hmm, I seem to be getting an empty array, is my api service correct? Am i supposed to be doing .map and then .flatMap again>
            public findAll(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
                return this.http
                .get((this.originAll + endpoint))
                .map(this.extractTextData)
                .catch(this.handleError);

        }

Comment: `this.apiService.findAll("virtualhosts/deltest").do(console.log).flatMap(data => this.apiService.findVH(data.VirtualHosts)).subscribe(console.log)` . You will get two logs, tell what they are

Comment: I am now receiving a list of ID's. I need to pass this array to findVH which must call get for each of these ID's. How would I pass this array to findVH (get call)?